# How to plot histogram of columns of a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, histogram

I have to plot a histogram of each column of `MatrixE1`. How can I go about doing this? This is what I have written so far.

```
% Create a random 5 x 3 matrix filled with random values between 0 and 10
a0 = 0;
b0 = 10;
r = a0 + (b0-a0).*rand(1,1);
matrixA = [randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]); randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]); randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]); randi([0 10])      randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]); randi([0 10]) randi([0 10]) randi([0 10])]
% Create identity matrix 3 x 3 
matrixB = eye(3,3) 

% Create new submatrix of A with the last 3 rows
matrixC =  matrixA(end-2 : end, :) 

%  Pair wise multiplication of C and B
matrixD = times(matrixC, matrixB)  

%  Concatenate Matrix A and D
matrixE1 = [matrixA ; matrixD]

% Plot histogram of columns. 
matrixColumn1 = matrixE1(1 : end , end-2: end-2);  
matrixFColumn2 = matrixE1(1 : end, end -1 : end-1);
matrixFColumn3 = matrixE1(1 : end, end : end);
```

Comment: Did you try `hist()`?

Comment: What would I do? hist(??). How can I get one histogram of all the columns of matrixE1? Should I do hist(matrixE1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access each of your coloumns in matrixE1 like this:

```
firstCol = matrixE1(:,1);
secondCol = matrixE1(:,2);
thirdCol = matrixE1(:,3);
```

...and then you can simply use comand hist() to plot histograms. You would plot histogram of first coloumn in matrixE1 as:

```
hist(firstCol);
```

And if I understand your second question: 
*''What would I do? hist(??). How can I get one histogram of all the columns of matrixE1? Should I do hist(matrixE1)?''* 
You can simply use command hold on after ploting histogram of one coloumn. Then plot another histogram on the same plot. For example if you want to plot histogram of first and second coloumn from matrixE1 to the same plot, you would type:

```
hist(firstCol);
hold on;
hist(secondCol);
```

Comment: **Update:** From the documentation: "`hist` is not recommended. Use [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) instead."  Updated [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846729/8239061).

Answer (score 2):

```
>> v1=randn(1000,1); % zero mean, unity stdev
>> v2=randn(1000,1)+1; % mean at one, unity stdev
>> V=[v1 v2]; % 1000 x 2 matrix
>> hist(V,100); % 100 bins
>> legend('v1', 'v2');
```

[image]

Comment: **Update:** From the documentation: "`hist` is not recommended. Use [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) instead."  Updated [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846729/8239061).

Answer (score 1):

There is another, simpler but computationally more expensive way:

```
plotmatrix(A)
```

For any matrix A this will produce a m-by-n plot of scatterplots of all pairwise combinations of your input matrix (**do not do this for large matrices, larger than you could fit on your screen**).

---

What you gain on top are histograms along the main diagonal of the plotmatrix.

---

Comment: This is a nifty trick. One note....how does this address the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034513/how-to-plot-histogram-of-columns-of-a-matrix/58846729#comment67346635_40034513) wanting all columns visualized in the same histogram plot?  When I run your code, it has them in separate subplots along the main diagonal.

Comment: Correct, I have missed that part of his requirements. In that case I would have overlaid the individual plots from the output. Your solution is more complete, requires some understanding of the data to scale correctly, yes?

Comment: I'm not sure too much understanding is required given the nature of MATLAB matrices. But regardless of the plot *how*, there are practical limits to stuffing too much into one visualization (or different domain scales) which would occur for any method.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer due to other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40042537/8239061), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40035229/8239061)) using outdated function `hist`.

MATLAB recommends avoiding the use of `hist` and now favors [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) ([source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/replace-discouraged-instances-of-hist-and-histc.html)). The changeover is straightforward.

[image: Histogram showing frequency of 3 difference columns of matrix A.]

```
% MATLAB R2019a
% Sample Data
NumPoints = 2000;
a1 = 10*rand(NumPoints,1);
a2 = wblrnd(3,7,NumPoints,1);
a3 = 7 + 0.75*randn(NumPoints,1);
A = [a1 a2 a3];                      % Data Matrix

% Implement Sturges Rule for n<=500, Scott's Rule for n>500
nbinsh =@(n) ceil((1 + 3.3*log10(n))*(n<=500) + ((5/3)*(n^(1/3)))*(n>500));
NumBins = nbinsh(NumPoints);

numCols = size(A,2);

% Plot
figure, hold on
for k = 1:numCols
    histogram(A(:,k),'NumBins',NumBins,'DisplayName',['Col ' num2str(k)]);
end
legend('show')
```

You can adjust from frequency (counts) to probability or probability density function depending on the application needs with the `Normalization` property (see [documentation here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram-properties.html#buh9u5j-1_sep_shared-Normalization)).